# Can Babel make Number.prototype.toLocaleString() work alike in React Native on all phones?

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, polyfills

I'm using `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` to get rounding and thousands separators working nicely with world currencies in my first React Native app.

It works great in the iOS but not on Android. I guess the different JS engines have differing support for `toLocaleString`.

I understand that BabelJS has support for polyfills but don't understand fully what it does and does not cover and cannot find information on this function in particular.

Is there a way I can get it to work in RN using Babl to polyfill it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking up a polyfill for `Number#toLocaleString()`, I found [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-tolocalestring-polyfill), and it does not require babel to use. In order to activate it in your code, put this line somewhere before you need it :

```
// recommended
require('number-tolocalestring-polyfill')()
```

If you need to force the polyfill to load, even if it detects that the environment already supports `Number#toLocaleString()` you can do this:

```
// probably for debug purposes only
require('number-tolocalestring-polyfill')(true)
```

Comment: In my case, it seemed both platforms supported `Number#toLocaleString` but not all of its features. I'll give it a try - thanks!

Looking at its source code I can't see what features it actually does support. It explicitly doesn't support currencies. It doesn't seem to support `useGrouping` for thousands separators, which I'm using: https://runkit.com/embed/yhv29j5sybvn